# how to map datatable's Index to datagridview's rowId?

Tags: c#

i am writing a viewer using datagridview to load a text file and display an m row x n column table (the table is editable by the user).

the main aim of this viewer is to change the backcolor of the max in each column to red, and the min of each column to green, and also cells that exceeds a certain threshold to  pink. (i use a button to trigger the checkMinMax() method, which iterates through each column of the dataTable to extract lists of rows for min/max/exceed )

i am able to do this when i first load the data into the datatable. however, when i sort the datagridview and call the checkMinMax() again, the color is still fixed at the old position.

```
public void setCellBackColor (List<int> rows, int col, Color color)
{
    foreach (int row in rows)
    { 
        dataGridView_data.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor = color;  
    }
}
```

i understand that i am using the index of the datatable rather than the rowId of the datagridview. so my question is if there is a way to map my datatable's index to the rowId?

or is there a better way to do what i want to do ?

Comment: The code you have, `List<int> col` and `Color col` have the same name, plus in the for each loop, col is being used (assuming the list) but wouldn't you need a single integer, not a list here? I'm guessing this is just pseudocode to give an idea what you are doing?

Comment: yup, it's just a pseudo code. yes you are right, column is just int instead of a List. i will update the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just recall your `setCellBackColumn` after sorting your data. Row highlighting is not dynamic, so you have to recall it. You may do so by using the `Sorted` event of the grid. Don't forget to specifically set the default color as white so it doesn't keep the outdated colors.